# Why do I get "Exception; must be caught or declared to be thrown" when I try to compile my Java code?

Tags: java, exception

Consider:

```
import java.awt.*;

import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.crypto.*;
import javax.crypto.spec.*;
import java.security.*;
import java.io.*;


public class EncryptURL extends JApplet implements ActionListener {

    Container content;
    JTextField userName = new JTextField();
    JTextField firstName = new JTextField();
    JTextField lastName = new JTextField();
    JTextField email = new JTextField();
    JTextField phone = new JTextField();
    JTextField heartbeatID = new JTextField();
    JTextField regionCode = new JTextField();
    JTextField retRegionCode = new JTextField();
    JTextField encryptedTextField = new JTextField();

    JPanel finishPanel = new JPanel();


    public void init() {

        //setTitle("Book - E Project");
        setSize(800, 600);
        content = getContentPane();
        content.setBackground(Color.yellow);
        content.setLayout(new BoxLayout(content, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));

        JButton submit = new JButton("Submit");

        content.add(new JLabel("User Name"));
        content.add(userName);

        content.add(new JLabel("First Name"));
        content.add(firstName);

        content.add(new JLabel("Last Name"));
        content.add(lastName);

        content.add(new JLabel("Email"));
        content.add(email);

        content.add(new JLabel("Phone"));
        content.add(phone);

        content.add(new JLabel("HeartBeatID"));
        content.add(heartbeatID);

        content.add(new JLabel("Region Code"));
        content.add(regionCode);

        content.add(new JLabel("RetRegionCode"));
        content.add(retRegionCode);

        content.add(submit);

        submit.addActionListener(this);
    }


    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

        if (e.getActionCommand() == "Submit"){

            String subUserName = userName.getText();
            String subFName = firstName.getText();
            String subLName = lastName.getText();
            String subEmail = email.getText();
            String subPhone = phone.getText();
            String subHeartbeatID = heartbeatID.getText();
            String subRegionCode = regionCode.getText();
            String subRetRegionCode = retRegionCode.getText();

            String concatURL =
                "user=" + subUserName + "&f=" + subFName +
                "&l=" + subLName + "&em=" + subEmail +
                "&p=" + subPhone + "&h=" + subHeartbeatID +
                "&re=" + subRegionCode + "&ret=" + subRetRegionCode;

            concatURL = padString(concatURL, ' ', 16);
            byte[] encrypted = encrypt(concatURL);
            String encryptedString = bytesToHex(encrypted);
            content.removeAll();
            content.add(new JLabel("Concatenated User Input -->" + concatURL));

            content.add(encryptedTextField);
            setContentPane(content);
        }
    }

    public static byte[] encrypt(String toEncrypt) throws Exception{
        try{
            String plaintext = toEncrypt;
            String key = "01234567890abcde";
            String iv = "fedcba9876543210";

            SecretKeySpec keyspec = new SecretKeySpec(key.getBytes(), "AES");
            IvParameterSpec ivspec = new IvParameterSpec(iv.getBytes());

            Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/NoPadding");
            cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, keyspec, ivspec);
            byte[] encrypted = cipher.doFinal(toEncrypt.getBytes());

            return encrypted;
        }
        catch(Exception e){
        }
    }


    public static byte[] decrypt(byte[] toDecrypt) throws Exception{
        String key = "01234567890abcde";
        String iv = "fedcba9876543210";

        SecretKeySpec keyspec = new SecretKeySpec(key.getBytes(), "AES");
        IvParameterSpec ivspec = new IvParameterSpec(iv.getBytes());

        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/NoPadding");
        cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, keyspec, ivspec);
        byte[] decrypted = cipher.doFinal(toDecrypt);

        return decrypted;
    }


    public static String bytesToHex(byte[] data) {
        if (data == null)
        {
            return null;
        }
        else
        {
            int len = data.length;
            String str = "";
            for (int i=0; i<len; i++)
            {
                if ((data[i]&0xFF) < 16)
                    str = str + "0" + java.lang.Integer.toHexString(data[i]&0xFF);
                else
                    str = str + java.lang.Integer.toHexString(data[i]&0xFF);
            }
            return str;
        }
    }


    public static String padString(String source, char paddingChar, int size)
    {
        int padLength = size-source.length() % size;
        for (int i = 0; i < padLength; i++) {
            source += paddingChar;
        }
        return source;
    }
}
```

I'm getting an unreported exception:

```
java.lang.Exception; must be caught or declared to be thrown
byte[] encrypted = encrypt(concatURL);
```

As well as:

```
.java:109: missing return statement
```

How do I solve these problems?

Comment: You should generate a different IV each time you encrypt. The IV doesn't need to be kept secret; just pass it around with the encrypted content.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

All your problems derive from this

```
byte[] encrypted = cipher.doFinal(toEncrypt.getBytes());
return encrypted;
```

Which are enclosed in a try, catch block, the problem is that in case the program found an exception you are not returning anything. Put it like this (modify it as your program logic stands):

```
public static byte[] encrypt(String toEncrypt) throws Exception{
    try{
        String plaintext = toEncrypt;
        String key = "01234567890abcde";
        String iv = "fedcba9876543210";

        SecretKeySpec keyspec = new SecretKeySpec(key.getBytes(), "AES");
        IvParameterSpec ivspec = new IvParameterSpec(iv.getBytes());

        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/NoPadding");
        cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE,keyspec,ivspec);
        byte[] encrypted = cipher.doFinal(toEncrypt.getBytes());

        return encrypted;
    } catch(Exception e){
        return null;            // Always must return something
    }
}
```

For the second one you must catch the Exception from the *encrypt* method call, like this (also modify it as your program logic stands):

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
  .
  .
  .
    try {
        byte[] encrypted = encrypt(concatURL);
        String encryptedString = bytesToHex(encrypted);
        content.removeAll();
        content.add(new JLabel("Concatenated User Input -->" + concatURL));

        content.add(encryptedTextField);
    setContentPane(content);
    } catch (Exception exc) {
        // TODO: handle exception
    }
}
```

The lessons you must learn from this:

- A method with a return-type must **always** return an object of that type, I mean in all possible scenarios
- All checked exceptions must **always** be handled

Comment: The last bullet point isn't exactly right. RuntimeException, a subclass of Exception, and its subclasses, are unchecked exceptions and do not need to be caught or declared to be thrown.

Answer (score 10):

The problem is in this method:

```
  public static byte[] encrypt(String toEncrypt) throws Exception{
```

This is the ***method signature*** which pretty much says:

- what the method name is: **encrypt**
- what parameter it receives: a String named **toEncrypt**
- its access modifier: **public static**
- and if it may or not **throw** an exception when invoked.

In this case the method signature says that when invoked this method "could" potentially throw an exception of type "Exception".

```
    ....
    concatURL = padString(concatURL, ' ', 16);
    byte[] encrypted = encrypt(concatURL); <-- HERE!!!!!
    String encryptedString = bytesToHex(encrypted);
    content.removeAll();
    ......
```

So the compilers is saying: Either you surround that with a try/catch construct or you declare the method ( where is being used ) to throw "Exception" it self.

The real problem is the "encrypt" method definition. No method should ever return "Exception", because it is too generic and may hide some other [kinds of exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/528917/why-dont-you-have-to-explicitly-declare-that-you-might-throw-some-built-in-excep/528942#528942) better is to have an specific exception.

Try this:

```
public static byte[] encrypt(String toEncrypt) {
    try{
      String plaintext = toEncrypt;
      String key = "01234567890abcde";
      String iv = "fedcba9876543210";

      SecretKeySpec keyspec = new SecretKeySpec(key.getBytes(), "AES");
      IvParameterSpec ivspec = new IvParameterSpec(iv.getBytes());

      Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/NoPadding");
      cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE,keyspec,ivspec);
      byte[] encrypted = cipher.doFinal(toEncrypt.getBytes());

      return encrypted;
    } catch ( NoSuchAlgorithmException nsae ) { 
        // What can you do if the algorithm doesn't exists??
        // this usually won't happen because you would test 
        // your code before shipping. 
        // So in this case is ok to transform to another kind 
        throw new IllegalStateException( nsae );
    } catch ( NoSuchPaddingException nspe ) { 
       // What can you do when there is no such padding ( whatever that means ) ??
       // I guess not much, in either case you won't be able to encrypt the given string
        throw new IllegalStateException( nsae );
    }
    // line 109 won't say it needs a return anymore.
  }
```

Basically in this particular case you should make sure the cryptography package is available in the system.

Java needs an extension for the cryptography package, so, the exceptions are declared as "checked" exceptions. For you to handle when they are not present.

In this small program you cannot do anything if the cryptography package is not available, so you check that at "development" time. If those exceptions are thrown when your program is running is because you did something wrong in "development" thus a RuntimeException subclass is more appropriate.

The last line don't need a return statement anymore, in the first version you were catching the exception and doing nothing with it, that's wrong.

```
try { 
    // risky code ... 
} catch( Exception e ) { 
    // a bomb has just exploited
    // you should NOT ignore it 
} 

// The code continues here, but what should it do???
```

If the code is to fail, it is better to [Fail fast](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fail-fast)

Here are some related answers:

- [Catching Exceptions in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/534718/catching-exceptions-in-java/534939#534939)
- [When to choose checked and unchecked exceptions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27578/when-to-choose-checked-and-unchecked-exceptions)
- [Why don’t you have to explicitly declare that you might throw some built in exceptions in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/528917/why-dont-you-have-to-explicitly-declare-that-you-might-throw-some-built-in-excep/528942#528942)
- [Exception other than RuntimeException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/462501/exception-other-than-runtimeexception/462745#462745)

Answer (score 6):

The first error

> java.lang.Exception; must be caught or declared to be thrown byte[] encrypted = encrypt(concatURL);

means that your `encrypt` method throws an exception that is not being handled or declared by the `actionPerformed` method where you are calling it.  Read all about it at the [Java Exceptions Tutorial](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/essential/exceptions/).

You have a couple of choices that you can pick from to get the code to compile.

- You can remove `throws Exception` from your `encrypt` method and *actually handle* the exception inside `encrypt`.
- You can remove the try/catch block from `encrypt` and add `throws Exception` and the exception handling block to your `actionPerformed` method.

It's generally better to handle an exception at the lowest level that you can, instead of passing it up to a higher level.

The second error just means that you need to add a return statement to whichever method contains line 109 (also `encrypt`, in this case).  There is a return statement in the method, but if an exception is thrown it might not be reached, so you either need to return in the catch block, or remove the try/catch from `encrypt`, as I mentioned before.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to decide how you'd like to handle exceptions thrown by the `encrypt` method.

Currently, `encrypt` is declared with `throws Exception` - however, in the body of the method, exceptions are caught in a try/catch block. I recommend you either:

- remove the `throws Exception` clause from `encrypt` and handle exceptions internally (**consider writing a log message at the very least**); or,
- remove the try/catch block from the body of `encrypt`, and surround the *call* to `encrypt` with a try/catch instead (i.e. in `actionPerformed`).

Regarding the compilation error you refer to: if an exception was thrown in the `try` block of `encrypt`, nothing gets returned after the `catch` block finishes. You could address this by initially declaring the return value as `null`:

```
public static byte[] encrypt(String toEncrypt) throws Exception{
  byte[] encrypted = null;
  try {
    // ...
    encrypted = ...
  }
  catch(Exception e){
    // ...
  }
  return encrypted;
}
```

However, if you can correct the bigger issue (the exception-handling strategy), this problem will take care of itself - particularly if you choose the second option I've suggested.

Answer (score 0):

In `actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)` you call `encrypt()`, which is declared to throw `Exception`.  However, `actionPerformed` neither catches this Exception (with try/catch around the call to `encrypt()`) nor declares that it throws `Exception` itself.

Your `encrypt` method, however, does not truly throw `Exception`.  It swallows all Exceptions without even as much as logging a complaint.  (Bad practice and bad style!)

Also, your `encrypt` method does the following:

```
public static byte[] encrypt(String toEncrypt) throws Exception {
  try{
    ....
    return encrypted; // HERE YOU CORRECTLY RETURN A VALUE
  } catch(Exception e) {
  }
  // YOU DO NOT RETURN ANYTHING HERE
}
```

That is, if you do catch any Exception, you discard it silently and then fall off the bottom of your `encrypt` method without actually returning anything.  This won't compile (as you see), because a method that is declared to return a value must either return a value or throw an Exception for every single possible code path.

Answer (score 0):

In your 'encrypt' method, you should either get rid of the try/catch and instead add a try/catch around where you call encrypt (inside 'actionPerformed') or return null inside the catch within encrypt (that's the second error.