# Why get NoSuchAlgorithmException when Providers are available

Tags: java, algorithm, exception, encryption, cryptography

First, i ran this:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    for (Provider provider: Security.getProviders()) {
      System.out.println(provider.getName());
      for (String key: provider.stringPropertyNames())
        System.out.println("\t" + key + "\t" + provider.getProperty(key));
    }
  }
```

Got:

```
Cipher.AES SupportedModes   ECB|CBC|PCBC|CTR|CTS|CFB|OFB|CFB8|CFB16|CFB24|CFB32|CFB40|CFB48|CFB56|CFB64|OFB8|OFB16|OFB24|OFB32|OFB40|OFB48|OFB56|OFB64|CFB72|CFB80|CFB88|CFB96|CFB104|CFB112|CFB120|CFB128|OFB72|OFB80|OFB88|OFB96|OFB104|OFB112|OFB120|OFB128
    Cipher.AES_128/OFB/NoPadding    com.sun.crypto.provider.AESCipher$AES128_OFB_NoPadding
    Cipher.AESWrap SupportedModes   ECB
    Cipher.AES SupportedKeyFormats  RAW
    Cipher.AES  com.sun.crypto.provider.AESCipher$General
    Provider.id info    SunJCE Provider (implements RSA, DES, Triple DES, AES, Blowfish, ARCFOUR, RC2, PBE, Diffie-Hellman, HMAC)
    Cipher.AES SupportedPaddings    NOPADDING|PKCS5PADDING|ISO10126PADDING
```

But when I try to `getInstance()` of Cipher "AES/ECB/PKCS5PADDING", it jump to exception:

```
test.java:43: error: unreported exception NoSuchAlgorithmException; must be caught or declared to be thrown
        Cipher cip = Cipher.getInstance("AES/ECB/PKCS5PADDING");
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why do I get "Exception; must be caught or declared to be thrown" when I try to compile my Java code?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/908672/why-do-i-get-exception-must-be-caught-or-declared-to-be-thrown-when-i-try-to)

Comment: No. You're saying the difference thing. I mean that javax.crypto support to AES algorith/ECB mode/PKCS5PADDING, but why exception occurred?

Comment: The compiler is raising an error, an exception is not being thrown.

Comment: @DarthAndroid Okay i known it bro, but it isn't my question

Comment: Then change your question. Because right now you're asking about a compilation error.

Comment: Engligh isn't my primary language, so I don't know how to explain clearly in the question title, can you give me? @Pillar

Comment: You seem to be asking about the error `unreported exception NoSuchAlgorithmException; must be caught or declared to be thrown`.  That is a compilation error. That is already answered in the linked duplicate. You're not handling the exception in the source code.

Comment: Have you read my question at all?

Comment: I literally copy-pasted the error you have in your question body.

Comment: Im not expecting any answer that such like `you didn't thrown exception` or `you didn't handled exception`. I want to know why exception occurred...

Comment: You haven't shown any exception occurring...You've shown a compilation error that indicates you didn't handle an exception either with a `try-catch` or with a `throws` declaration. I don't know what else to tell you.

Comment: Okay, won't the compilation error tell that exception occur? If i use `try-catch`, then surely jump to exception :)

Comment: No. You're confusing compile time and runtime. A compilation error tells you that your source code is invalid Java code. A thrown exception during program execution tells you that something misbehaved at runtime.

Comment: Ah, sorry. I know, but, again, quite difficult for me to explain. I mean the first code snipet show my java system does support AES algorithm/ECB mode and PKCS5PADDING, so why this compilation error occurred...

Comment: :( Because you haven't handled the possible exception with a `throws` or a `try-catch`..............

Comment: Oh, gotcha...
So now i know that when handled possible exception will avoid this compilation error. Thank you very much.

BTW, Sorry for anything make you uncomfortable from starting of conversion :)

Answer (score -1):

Take a look at [Cipher Algorithm Names](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/security/StandardNames.html#Cipher) in the documentation.  You're getting a list of providers, not Ciphers.