# Reading EXCEL file in Java using jxl

Tags: java, excel, jxl

I have a problem with reading xls files into Java usin jxl library.

Could you tell me what is wrong my code? I attached below. Something is wrong wif fillData method. The console returns:

```
Exception in thread "Thread-1" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at StudentLogin.fillData(StudentLogin.java:104)
    at StudentLogin.<init>(StudentLogin.java:70)
    at Login$PBar.run(Login.java:103)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Thank you in advance for your help.

```
 public void fillData(File file) {
            Workbook workbook = null;
            try {
                workbook = Workbook.getWorkbook(file);
            }
            catch (Exception e) {
            }

            Sheet sheet = workbook.getSheet(0);

            headers.clear();
            for (int i = 0; i < sheet.getColumns(); i++) {
                Cell cell = sheet.getCell(i, 0);
                headers.add(cell.getContents());
            }

            data.clear();
            for (int j = 1; j < sheet.getRows(); j++) {
                Vector<String> d = new Vector<String>();
                for (int i = 0; i < sheet.getColumns(); i++) {
                    Cell cell = sheet.getCell(i, j);
                    d.add(cell.getContents());
                }
                d.add("\n");
                data.add(d);
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you to take a look at two parts of the method `fillData`:

1) `try-catch` probably hides the problem:  in the beginning, you call the method `getWorkbook` which, according to its [java doc](http://jexcelapi.sourceforge.net/resources/javadocs/2_6_10/docs/jxl/Workbook.html#getWorkbook(java.io.File)), can throw an exception if, for instance, the file does not exist. However, you call the `getWorkbook` in a `try-catch` block which does not even print the exception. Consequently, if anything goes wrong you will get a null pointer at `workbook.getSheet(0)` cause the variable `workbook` keeps holding a null value (as you assign null in the first line of the method). To avoid this problem you can add a `printStackTrace` in the catch block. Another option is to add a `throws Exception` in the method definition and remove the `try-catch` block. Doing this, you may find the real cause of the null pointer.

```
 try {
      workbook = Workbook.getWorkbook(file);
 } catch (Exception e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
 }
```

OR

```
public void fillData(File file) throws Exception {

 Workbook workbook = Workbook.getWorkbook(file);
 ....
}
```

2) Is the variable headers globally initialized? I can't see in your code where you initialize the variable headers (doing like `headers = new ArrayList()`). If you did not do it, you will get a null pointer at `headers.clear()`. Moreover, the same problem can happen with the variable `data` if you don't initialize it.

Comment: Thank you. I used the second option and now I have following problem: 
    Error:(88, 41) java: unreported exception java.lang.Exception; must be caught or declared to be thrown
    Error:(73, 25) java: unreported exception java.lang.Exception; must be caught or declared to be thrown

I initalized a headers in the beginning of my class so it could work well.

     private Vector<String> headers = new Vector<String>();

Comment: It seems to be a compiler error. For more information, see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/908672/why-do-i-get-exception-must-be-caught-or-declared-to-be-thrown-when-i-try-to