# File Scanner: Unreported exception FileNotFoundException; must be caught or declared to be thrown

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

I have tried everything I can find on the internet, and nothing seems to fix this. I am begging for help, tell me what I am doing wrong. I am brand new to Java. Thanks!

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class File_Scanner {    
    public static void read() {
        File credentials_file = new File("credentials.txt");
        Scanner file_reader = new Scanner(credentials_file);
        String[] users = new String[6];
        int index_counter = 0;

        try {
            while (file_reader.hasNextLine()) {
                users[index_counter] = file_reader.nextLine();
            }
            file_reader.close();

        } catch (Exception e) {
          System.out.println(e.getClass());
        }
    }
}
```

This is showing the following error

```
Unreported exception FileNotFoundException; must be caught or declared to be thrown
```

Comment: The line number on the compiler error should tell you exactly what line could throw that exception.

Comment: Read up on "checked exceptions".  Make better code but is occasionally very painful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would like to recommend to surround the whole `read` function with a `try/catch` block like the following.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class File_Scanner{    
    public static void read(){
        try {
            File credentials_file = new File("credentials.txt");
            Scanner file_reader = new Scanner(credentials_file);
            String[] users = new String[6];
            int index_counter = 0;

            while (file_reader.hasNextLine()) {
                users[index_counter] = file_reader.nextLine();
            }

            file_reader.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
          System.out.println(e.getClass());
        }
    }
}
```

The idea of `try/catch` is to avoid any error that might occur while running your program. In your case, `Scanner file_reader = new Scanner(credentials_file);` can throw an error if the `credentials_file` is not found or deleted. Hence you need to cover this around a `try` block which will give you an exception which can be handled to show proper response message in the `catch` block.

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 2):

I agree with the other answers as to the problem (the `Scanner` can throw an exception if it can't find the file).  I haven't seen what I'd consider the correct solution though.

```
    String[] users = new String[6];
    int index_counter = 0;

    File credentials_file = new File("credentials.txt");
    try (Scanner file_reader = new Scanner(credentials_file)) {
        while (file_reader.hasNextLine()) {
            users[index_counter] = file_reader.nextLine();
            index_counter++;
        }
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        // handle exception
    } catch (NoSuchElementException e) {
        // handle exception
    } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
        // handle exception
    }
```

The [try-with-resources](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) statement will automatically close the `Scanner` for you.  This will work with any class that implements the `AutoCloseable` interface.

And in this case, it puts the statement within the scope of the `try`, so exceptions will be caught.

Your exception handling is questionable, so I didn't include it.  But that's not really the point here.  You can read more about [Best Practices to Handle Exceptions in Java](https://stackify.com/best-practices-exceptions-java/) or [How to Specify and Handle Exceptions in Java](https://stackify.com/specify-handle-exceptions-java/).

There is an argument that you should let the exception bubble up to the caller.  [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54796996/6660678) describes how to do that.  But in this case, the caller doesn't really know how to handle a `FileNotFoundException`, because it doesn't know anything about the file.  The file is defined in this method.

You could throw a different, more explanatory exception.  Or you could handle the exception here by explaining what a `credentials.txt` is.  Or fail over to a default.  Or just log the exception, although that's questionable.  If you do that, you should explain (in a comment) why that is sufficient.

I added a line to increment `index_counter` just because it seemed to be missing.

See also

- [Why do I get "Exception; must be caught or declared to be thrown" when I try to compile my Java code?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/908672/6660678)
- [Am I using the Java 7 try-with-resources correctly](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17650970/6660678)?

Answer (score 1):

Java has checked exceptions. Which means that if the code within your method declares that it might possibly throw a particular exception, your method either needs to do one of the following:

Either (1) handle that exception:

```
public static void read() {
    try {
        // your method code
    } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
        // handle the exception
    }
}
```

Or (2) declare that it might possibly throw that exception:

```
public static void read() throws FileNotFoundException {
    // your method code
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just add this to your method declaration:

```
public static void read() throws FileNotFoundException
```

For ways to handle checked exceptions in java check [this(Oracle Docs Java Tutorials)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/catch.html):

> You associate exception handlers with a try block by providing one or
>   more catch blocks directly after the try block. No code can be between
>   the end of the try block and the beginning of the first catch block.
>
> try {
>
> } catch (ExceptionType name) {
>
> } catch (ExceptionType name) {
>
> }

And [this](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/declaring.html):

> Sometimes, it's
>   appropriate for code to catch exceptions that can occur within it. In
>   other cases, however, it's better to let a method further up the call
>   stack handle the exception
>
> public void writeList() throws IOException {

P.S. Also, it has been already [discussed on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/908672/why-do-i-get-exception-must-be-caught-or-declared-to-be-thrown-when-i-try-to), so maybe should be marked as duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

You should read the java checked exception

```
public static void read() {
    try {
        File credentials_file = new File("credentials.txt");
        Scanner file_reader;
        file_reader = new Scanner(credentials_file);
        String[] users = new String[6];
        int index_counter = 0;

        while (file_reader.hasNextLine()) {
            users[index_counter] = file_reader.nextLine();
        }
        file_reader.close();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e1.printStackTrace();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e.getClass());
    }
}
```