# Is it the best practice to catch thowrable?

Tags: java

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is it a bad practice to catch the Throwable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6083248/is-it-a-bad-practice-to-catch-the-throwable)

Is it best practice to catch throwable?  If catching throwable, will it catch out of memory etc exception?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bjava%5D+catch+throwable

Comment: Although this might be more appropriate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/581878/why-catch-exceptions-in-java-when-you-can-catch-throwables

Answer (score 0):

The only way to catch `Throwable` exception, is the same as that you catch Exceptions. How it works is, it catch the exceptions/error by the hierarchy tree.

So if you wanna catch `OutOfMemory` Error you have some options:

```java
try{
}catch(java.lang.OutOfMemoryError t){
}

try{
}catch(java.lang.Error t){
}

try{
}catch(java.lang.Throwable t){
}
```

Just check the class tree in the docs for the exception that you wanna catch.
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/OutOfMemoryError.html

Also a good practice is among your catch blocks always start with the ones with are in the bottom of the tree, so for example:

```java
try{
//
}catch(java.lang.OutOfMemoryError t){
// handle out of memory error
}catch(java.lang.Throwable t){
// handle other throwable
}
```

Also remember that Error and Exception they both extend Throwable, but they dont extend each other so both are siblings in the class tree.