# How can Java programs crash when exceptions must always be caught?

Tags: java, exception

Forgive me if this is a stupid question, but as far as I know, all Java exceptions must be caught and handled.
For example, something like this would create a compiler error:

```
public String foo(Object o) {
    if (o instanceof Boolean) {
        throw new Exception();
    }
    return o.toString();
}
```

Because the method `foo()` didn't add a `throws` clause.
However, this example would work (unless either the method `foo()` didn't have a `throws` clause or the method `bar()` didn't surround usage of `foo()` in a `try/catch` block):

```
public String foo(Object o) throws Exception {
    if (o instanceof Boolean) {
        throw new Exception();
    }
    return o.toString();
}

public void bar(Object o) {
    try {
        String s = foo(o);
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        //...
    }
    //...
}
```

At the end, sometimes a Java program still sometimes crashes due to an ***unhandled*** exception.

How does this happen?

Comment: They aren't always caught and handled. That's the issue.

Comment: All [**checked expressions**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/runtime.html) ...

Comment: Provide your stack trace so we can see what exception is.

Comment: There are also `Throwable` objects which aren't `Exception` objects. Thus your catch block will miss them. See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/581878/4856258).

Comment: Your JVM itself can also crash due to a bug or a bug in JNI code.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You don't have to handle *all* kinds of exceptions.

Exceptions that inherit from [`java.lang.RuntimeException`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/RuntimeException.html?is-external=true) or [`java.lang.Error`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Error.html) are so-called **unchecked exceptions** that can be caught by a try-catch construct, they don't have to be, though.

As you can see in the API docs of `java.lang.Error`, it does not inherit from `java.lang.Exception`. For this reason, it will not be caught by your try-catch block - you only look for `java.lang.Exception` and its subclasses.

Have a look at [this article in the docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/runtime.html).

Answer (score 1):

Some exceptions can be unchecked, these are known as Runtime Exceptions. For example an `IllegalArumentException` is an unchecked exception because it is a descendant of `java.lang.RuntimeException`. You can read about it [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/runtime.html).