# No way to catch route errors in Spark Java?

Tags: java, exception, spark-java

There is a static exception path on class Spark, but it only takes something that extends from Exception.  If an error occurs that is a Throwable, but does not extend Exception, there appears to be no way to catch it in the Spark API to log or handle it before a 500 is returned to client.

Example of a common type of Throwable that can't be mapped to Spark.exception:  java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError

Any way to get hold of these in Spark before they disappear out to client, without wrapping the functions of every route in a try/catch(Throwable)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't catch `Throwable` errors in Spark.

The thing is that `Throwable` includes `Error`
Error is programmatically unrecoverable and therefore is usually not to be caught.
On the other hand `Exception` is programmatically recoverable, and therefore something that you may want to catch.

I recommend you reading

- [Difference between using Throwable and Exception in a try catch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2274102/difference-between-using-throwable-and-exception-in-a-try-catch)
- [Why catch Exceptions in Java, when you can catch Throwables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/581878/why-catch-exceptions-in-java-when-you-can-catch-throwables)

You should ask yourself why are you trying to catch `Throwable`'s and maybe modify that part (if that code of yours).

Comment: Most API frameworks, like Jersey for example, are going to give you a catch-all hookpoint for Throwable, because regardless of whether it is recoverable or unrecoverable, an error is about to flow out to your client, and you want to at least log it before it does.  As Spark stands now, if a Java Error subclass is thrown, there is no way without explicit try / catch blocks in every endpoint method to log them before the 500 goes out to client.  Your answer is correct I think, though - and same conclusion I came to - they just don't have a way to do it.

Comment: As an aside, if you are willing to use aspects on a project, that could be done to be sure to log any throwable escaping a spark class.

Comment: Returning something to the client may be also imposible. In case an `Error` happens, it can be, for example, that you have no more memory. There is no guarantee to do things at that point. Although trying to log something could be good..