# Is it possible to call the main(String[] args) after catching an exception?

Tags: java, exception

I'm working on a Serpinski triangle program that asks the user for the levels of triangles to draw.  In the interests of idiot-proofing my program, I put this in:

```
Scanner input= new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println(msg);
try {
    level= input.nextInt();
} catch (Exception e) {
    System.out.print(warning);
    //restart main method
}
```

Is it possible, if the user punches in a letter or symbol, to restart the main method after the exception has been caught?

Comment: Why not just use a loop?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can prevent the `Scanner` from throwing `InputMismatchException` by using [`hasNextInt()`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#hasNextInt%28%29):

```
if (input.hasNextInt()) {
   level = input.nextInt();
   ...
}
```

This is an often forgotten fact: **you can always prevent** a `Scanner` from throwing `InputMismatchException` on `nextXXX()` by first ensuring `hasNextXXX()`.

But to answer your question, yes, you can invoke `main(String[])` just like any other method.

#### See also

- [(Java) Opinion: Preventing Exceptions vs. Catching Exceptions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/894829/java-opinion-preventing-exceptions-vs-catching-exceptions)
- [How do I keep a scanner from throwing exceptions when the wrong type is entered? (java)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2496239/how-do-i-keep-a-scanner-from-throwing-exceptions-when-the-wrong-type-is-entered)

---

*Note*: to use `hasNextXXX()` in a loop, you have to skip past the "garbage" input that causes it to return `false`. You can do this by, say, calling and discarding `nextLine()`.

```
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    while (!sc.hasNextInt()) {
        System.out.println("int, please!");
        sc.nextLine(); // discard!
    }
    int i = sc.nextInt(); // guaranteed not to throw InputMismatchException
```

Comment: your answer helped me the most, particularly the second link.  Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Well, you can call it recursively: `main(args)`, but you'd better use a `while` loop.

Comment: This is basically what I wanted to know, what argument to use inside the parenthesis to call the main method.

Comment: the one that has been passed to the main method - the `String[] args`

Comment: And of course, unlike a loop, this can only happen so many times before it `StackOverflowError`.

Answer (score 0):

You much better want to do this:

```
boolean loop = true;
Scanner input= new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println(msg);
do{
    try {
        level= input.nextInt();
        loop = false;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.print(warning);
        //restart main method
        loop = true;
    }
while(loop);
```