# Return 404 for every null response

Tags: http, spring-boot, httpresponse

I'd like to return 404 when the response object is null for every response automatically in spring boot.

I need suggestions.

I don't want to check object in controller that it is null or not.

Comment: You can read this topic : [spring boot exception handling](https://spring.io/blog/2013/11/01/exception-handling-in-spring-mvc)

Comment: I don't want to check object in controller if its nul or not ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need more than one Spring module to accomplish this. The basic steps are:

1. Declare an exception class that can be used to throw an exception when a repository method does not return an expected value.
2. Add a `@ControllerAdvice` that catches the custom exception and translates it into an HTTP `404` status code.
3. Add an AOP advice that intercepts return values of repository methods and raises the custom exception when it finds the values not matching expectations.

---

> **Step 1**: Exception class

```
public class ResourceNotFoundException extends RuntimeException {}
```

> **Step 2**: Controller advice

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class ResourceNotFoundExceptionHandler
{
  @ExceptionHandler(ResourceNotFoundException.class)
  @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND)
  public void handleResourceNotFound() {}
}
```

> **Step 3**: AspectJ advice

```
@Aspect
@Component
public class InvalidRepositoryReturnValueAspect
{
  @AfterReturning(pointcut = "execution(* org.example.data.*Repository+.findOne(..))", returning = "result")
  public void intercept(final Object result)
  {
    if (result == null)
    {
      throw new ResourceNotFoundException();
    }
  }
}
```

---

A sample application is available [on Github](https://github.com/manish-in-java/stackoverflow-questions/tree/master/43888003) to demonstrate all of this in action. Use a REST client like Postman for Google Chrome to add some records. Then, attempting to fetch an existing record by its identifier will return the record correctly but attempting to fetch one by a non-existent identifier will return `404`.

Comment: Intercepting repo returns is not a good idea I thing. Is it possible to intercept controller returns ?

Comment: If you use your own controllers for the REST API endpoints, sure, just change the pointcut to point to controller methods instead of repository methods.

Comment: You can use `ResponseStatusException(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND, "not found")` instead of custom exception + custom controller advice btw.
`org.springframework.web.server.ResponseStatusException`

Answer (score 4):

Simplest way to do this in Spring is write your own exception class like below

```
@ResponseStatus(value = HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND)
class ResourceNotFoundException extends RuntimeException{
}
```

Then just throw the ResourceNotFoundException from anywhere.

```
if (something == null) throw new ResourceNotFoundException();
```

For more -> [Read](https://spring.io/blog/2013/11/01/exception-handling-in-spring-mvc)

Comment: I don't want to check object in controller if its nul or not ?  I want to return 404 for all null responses for every request.

Comment: As i mentioned you can throw the exception from anywhere...from service or Dao

Comment: Tanks Amit, but I don't want to check any logic to send exception or sth. Just I want to return to client 404 if return object is null. I want a layer to manupulate response just before returning phase to client.

Comment: Then I will suggest you to go through Controller Advice. Hopefully this will help you https://spring.io/blog/2013/11/01/exception-handling-in-spring-mvc#using-controlleradvice-classes

Answer (score 3):

There is no need to throw exceptions, now `ResponseBodyAdvice` does the trick:

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class NullTo404 implements ResponseBodyAdvice<Object> {

    @Override
    public boolean supports(MethodParameter returnType, Class<? extends HttpMessageConverter<?>> converterType) {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public Object beforeBodyWrite(Object body, MethodParameter returnType, MediaType selectedContentType,
            Class<? extends HttpMessageConverter<?>> selectedConverterType, ServerHttpRequest request,
            ServerHttpResponse response) {
        if (body == null) {
            response.setStatusCode(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);
        }
        return body;
    }   
}
```

Similarly, you can implement `ResponseBodyAdvice<Optional<?>>`, and check for `Optional.isEmpty()` before setting the response status. It has the added benefit of working nicely with `CrudRepository`. Most controller methods eventually ends like this:

```
public Optional<Product> getProductBySku(@PathVariable String sku) {
    // logic goes here...
    return productRepository.findBySku(sku);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Similar to @manish's answer (https://stackoverflow.com/a/43891952/986160) but without the AspectJ pointcut and using another `@ControllerAdvice` instead:

> **Step 1:** NotFoundException class:

```
public class NotFoundException extends RuntimeException {
    public NotFoundException(String msg) {
        super(msg);
    }
    public NotFoundException() {}
}
```

> **Step 2:** Check if body returned in endpoint is null and throw NotFoundException:

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class NotFoundAdvice implements ResponseBodyAdvice {
    @Override
    public boolean supports(MethodParameter returnType, Class converterType) {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public Object beforeBodyWrite(Object body, MethodParameter returnType, MediaType selectedContentType, Class selectedConverterType, ServerHttpRequest request, ServerHttpResponse response) {
        if (body == null) {
            throw new NotFoundException("resource not found");
        }
        return body;
    }
}
```

> **Step 3:** handle NotFoundException and make the response have a status of 404

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class GlobalExceptionAdvice {

    @Data
    public class ErrorDetails {
        private Date timestamp;
        private String message;
        private String details;

        public ErrorDetails(Date timestamp, String message, String details) {
            super();
            this.timestamp = timestamp;
            this.message = message;
            this.details = details;
        }
    }

    @ExceptionHandler(NotFoundException.class)
    public final ResponseEntity<ErrorDetails> notFoundHandler(Exception ex, WebRequest request) {
        ErrorDetails errorDetails = new ErrorDetails(new Date(), ex.getMessage(),
                request.getDescription(false));
        return new ResponseEntity<>(errorDetails, HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);
    }
}
```

> **Alternative to Step 3:**

You can just annotate your `NotFoundException` with `@ResponseStatus` and override `fillInStackTrace()` (from https://stackoverflow.com/a/31263942/986160) so that it has similar effect to `GlobalExceptionAdvice` and doesn't show stacktrace like this:

```
@ResponseStatus(value = HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND,reason =  "resource not found")
public class NotFoundException extends RuntimeException {
    public NotFoundException(String msg) {
        super(msg);
    }
    public NotFoundException() {}

    @Override
    public synchronized Throwable fillInStackTrace() {
        return this;
    }
}
```