# How to handle exception in SpringBoot correctly, so the exception will not be bubbled up to server log?

Tags: java, spring-boot, wildfly

I have a RestController which throws custom exception, BoogyException is extended by RuntimeException.

RestController:

```
@RestController
public class Test {
    @GetMapping(path = "/test")    
    public ResponseEntity<String> myTest() {
       throws new BoogyException("I am a boog exception.");
    }
}
```

BoogyException:

```
public class BoogyException extends RunException {
    public BoogyException(Exception exception) {
      . ....
    }
}
```

My @ControllerAdvice class maps the BoogyException and return ResponseEntity.

```
@RestControllerAdvice
public class MotherExceptionHandler {

    @ExceptionHandler(value = { BoogyException.class})
    public ResponseEntity<MyJsonExcp> handleBoogyException(final Exception ex) {
           ....
    }
}
```

MyJsonExcp is simple POJO with Jackson annotations.

When my RestController throws BoogyException, I can see the JSON formatted response correctly. However, a RuntimeException
is logged as debug level by SpringBoot in my WildFly server's log also.

```
DEBUG [io.undertow.request.error-response] (default task-2) 
    Setting error code 500 for exchange HttpServerExchange{ GET /api/test
    request {cache-control=[max-age=0], accept-encoding=[gzip, deflate, br], 
    ... X-Frame-Options=[SAMEORIGIN]}}: java.lang.RuntimeException
        at io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange.setStatusCode(HttpServerExchange.java:1410)
        at io.undertow.servlet.spec.HttpServletResponseImpl.setStatus(HttpServletResponseImpl.java:286)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponseWrapper.setStatus(HttpServletResponseWrapper.java:245)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.HttpEntityMethodProcessor.handleReturnValue(HttpEntityMethodProcessor.java:201)
        at org.springframework.web.method.support.HandlerMethodReturnValueHandlerComposite.handleReturnValue(HandlerMethodReturnValueHandlerComposite.java:78)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:135)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver.doResolveHandlerMethodException(ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver.java:428)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerMethodExceptionResolver.doResolveException(AbstractHandlerMethodExceptionResolver.java:75)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerExceptionResolver.resolveException(AbstractHandlerExceptionResolver.java:142)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.HandlerExceptionResolverComposite.resolveException(HandlerExceptionResolverComposite.java:80)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.processHandlerException(DispatcherServlet.java:1327)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.processDispatchResult(DispatcherServlet.java:1138)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1084)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:963)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:898)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:686)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:791)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletHandler.handleRequest(ServletHandler.java:74)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:129)  
        at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:61)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131)
        at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:61)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131)
        at net.sourceforge.spnego.SpnegoHttpFilter.doFilter(SpnegoHttpFilter.java:318)
        at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:61)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117)
        at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:61)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117)
        at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:61)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131)
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.ErrorPageFilter.doFilter(ErrorPageFilter.java:126)
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.ErrorPageFilter.access$000(ErrorPageFilter.java:64)
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.ErrorPageFilter$1.doFilterInternal(ErrorPageFilter.java:101)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117)
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.ErrorPageFilter.doFilter(ErrorPageFilter.java:119)
        at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:61)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117)
        at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:61)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler.handleRequest(FilterHandler.java:84)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletSecurityRoleHandler.handleRequest(ServletSecurityRoleHandler.java:62)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletChain$1.handleRequest(ServletChain.java:68)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletDispatchingHandler.handleRequest(ServletDispatchingHandler.java:36)
        at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.SecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:78)
        at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.SSLInformationAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SSLInformationAssociationHandler.java:132)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.handleRequest(ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.java:57)
        at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
        at io.undertow.security.handlers.AuthenticationConstraintHandler.handleRequest(AuthenticationConstraintHandler.java:53)
        at io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractConfidentialityHandler.handleRequest(AbstractConfidentialityHandler.java:46)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.handleRequest(ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.java:64)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletSecurityConstraintHandler.handleRequest(ServletSecurityConstraintHandler.java:59)
        at io.undertow.security.handlers.AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.handleRequest(AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.java:60)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.handleRequest(CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.java:77)
        at io.undertow.security.handlers.NotificationReceiverHandler.handleRequest(NotificationReceiverHandler.java:50)
        at io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:43)
        at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
        at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.jacc.JACCContextIdHandler.handleRequest(JACCContextIdHandler.java:61)
        at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
        at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.GlobalRequestControllerHandler.handleRequest(GlobalRequestControllerHandler.java:68)
        at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
        at io.undertow.server.handlers.MetricsHandler.handleRequest(MetricsHandler.java:64)
        at io.undertow.servlet.core.MetricsChainHandler.handleRequest(MetricsChainHandler.java:59)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.handleFirstRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:292)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$100(ServletInitialHandler.java:81)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$2.call(ServletInitialHandler.java:138)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$2.call(ServletInitialHandler.java:135)
        at io.undertow.servlet.core.ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction$1.call(ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction.java:48)
        at io.undertow.servlet.core.ContextClassLoaderSetupAction$1.call(ContextClassLoaderSetupAction.java:43)
        at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.SecurityContextThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(SecurityContextThreadSetupAction.java:105)
        at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1502)
        at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1502)
        at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1502)
        at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1502)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.dispatchRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:272)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$000(ServletInitialHandler.java:81)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$1.handleRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:104)
        at io.undertow.server.Connectors.executeRootHandler(Connectors.java:364)
        at io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange$1.run(HttpServerExchange.java:830)
        at org.jboss.threads.ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.run(ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.java:35)
        at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor.safeRun(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1982)
        at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.doRunTask(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1486)
        at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1377)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

It looks like SpringBoot is bubbling my custom exception as RuntimeException to the server log.

Is there way to stop it?

Note: SpringBoot v2.7.0

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Prevent stack trace logging for custom exception in Spring Boot application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31250598/prevent-stack-trace-logging-for-custom-exception-in-spring-boot-application)

Comment: @NikolaiShevchenko, Thank you for the link. However, it did not work for me.

Comment: Because I am using WildFly server (external) and WildFly logging subsystem, I configure the WildFly logging subsystem to mitigate the issue.