# java class, exception, user input

Tags: java

I have a driven menu class using switch and beside that a class, that class throws an exception when a wrong input is entered how can I got back after the exception and ask the user to input data again.

java class diamond:

```
public class Diamond 
{

private int x;

    public Diamond(int x) throws IllegalArgumentException 
    {
        if ((x % 2) == 0) 
        {
           System.out.println("\nx must be odd.");
           throw new IllegalArgumentException("x must be odd.");

        }
      this.x = x;

    }
```

Comment: Why would you throw a runtime exception on invalid input?

Comment: Don't throw the exception....Just print a message to console: `System.out.println("Supplied value must be odd!");`.

Answer (score 0):

Please see [this question regarding exceptions in general](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2802358/what-is-an-exception-in-java) as well as [this Java Tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/index.html).

I assume you have some code that is accepting user input and then creating an instance of the `Diamond` class.

You would wrap the code creating the `Diamond` instance in a try-catch block.

So, something like this:

```
Diamond d = null;
try{
    d = new Diamond(userInput);
}catch(IllegalArgumentException e){
   //Handle the exception
}
```

However, since this exception is thrown due to an input problem rather than a programming problem I tend to lean toward the idea that you should use a checked exception here.

As a general rule per the [Java Tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/runtime.html):

> If a client can reasonably be expected to recover from an exception, make it a checked exception. If a client cannot do anything to recover from the exception, make it an unchecked exception.